# Rendering polygons with a VBO seems to lose some vertices

Tags: java, opengl, polygon, vbo

I'm trying to render a set of polygons, i have a set of points and im not doing any triangularization.

If i render my VBO with `GL_LINE_LOOP` mode, the lines went whit the right vertices, but when i try to render filled polygons with the same buffer but using `GL_POLYGON` i get wrong vertices, its like some points just go away.
I tried to disable the OpenGl polygon smoothing but still the same.

Any tips?

This image shows the lines and the polygon expected to be the same.

[image]

Comment: Can you take pictures of the two versions, and/or post some of your code?

Comment: image added, you can clearly see the diference betwen the lines and the filled polygon.

Answer (score 2):

`GL_POLYGON` is only for convex, coplanar polygons.

Make sure the points in your VBO form one.